# How to solve "jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "description""

Tags: json, bash, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

I use following script to get the description of a group in GitLab.

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash


GIT_API="https://git.xxxxxxxxxx.lk/api/v4"
GIT_TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxx"

curl -sS --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/1079" | jq -r ".[] .description"
```

But it outputs following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "description"
```

How to solve this problem.

curl output:

```json
{
  "id": 1079,
  "web_url": "https://git.xxxxxxxxxx.lk/groups/testdevops",
  "name": "testdevops20",
  "path": "testdevops",
  "description": "Test_1",
  "visibility": "private",
  "share_with_group_lock": false,
  "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
  "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
  "project_creation_level": "developer",
  "auto_devops_enabled": null,
  "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
  "emails_disabled": null,
  "mentions_disabled": null,
  "lfs_enabled": true,
  "default_branch_protection": 1,
  "avatar_url": null,
  "request_access_enabled": true,
  "full_name": "testdevops20",
  "full_path": "testdevops",
  "created_at": "2021-05-31T04:56:28.467Z",
  "parent_id": null,
  "shared_with_groups": [],
  "runners_token": "Dw_LPVsbeChD6s6n1wRy",
  "projects": []
}
```

Comment: Please, post the `cUrl` output to better understand where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the script as follow:

```sh
#! /bin/bash


GIT_API="https://git.xxxxxxxxxx.lk/api/v4"
GIT_TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxx"

curl -sS --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/1079" | jq -r ".description"
```

The `jq` command works if written as `jq -r ".description"`.